# Два "склеенных" окна с помощью tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Возник вопрос, а как сделать, пускай будет "склеенные" окна в tkinter. Вызываю из главного окнa дочернее и последнее должно появляеться впритык, как бы "склеенное" с первым и стать с ним неделимым, при перетаскивании оба окна меняли бы свое местоположение. Возможно даже оставался вариант с масштабированием окон кроме сторон соприкосновений. При закрытии вызываемого основное не гасилось бы.

Comment: Ну... чего странная задача... А зачем этo надо?

Comment: Взбрело в голову, хочу чтобы в приложухе было так. Делаю небольшой ежедневник и есть в нем окно с календарем. Так вот и хочу по нажатию кнопки с датой, чтобы всплывало справа окно с уже запланированными делами и возможностью добавления новых, по оси у равное окну с календарем, а по оси х на треть меньше. Вот тут и подумалось, а неплохо бы их сделать "склеенными" и неделимыми.

Comment: Эмм... Ну как с окнами я не знаю, там тупо надо прописать чего когда двигать, а мне лень ;). А то можно эту штуку как виджет реализовать и держать на прозрачном фоне?

Comment: Как хоть закрепить окно на экране, чтобы его нельзя было двигать.

Comment: `from tkinter import*;undraggable=Tk();undraggable.overrideredirect(True);mainloop()`